# Closedness of the image of the closed unit ball under a linear operator from a reflexive Banach space to an arbitrary Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a reflexive banach space. If $W$ is a Banach space and if $T$ is in $L(V,W)$, show that $T(B)$ is closed in $W$ where $B$ is closed unit ball in $V$,
the problem is in the chapter of weak and weak$^{\ast}$ topologies but I am not getting any hint what result I should use. please help.

Comment: You wrote that $T$ is a reflexive Banach space, but $T$ is the operator.  Is it $V$ or $W$ that should be reflexive?  Also, your questions will be easier to read and get more attention if you use complete sentences and correct grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you mean that $V$ is reflexive, since that's the only way that makes sense.

1. Since $V$ is reflexive, what can you say about the unit ball of $V$ (in a certain topology...)?
2. To show $T(B)$ is closed, suppose $v_n$ in $B$ with $Tv_n \to w$.  You need to produce $v \in B$ with $Tv = w$.  In light of the previous hint, can you think of a candidate for $v$?